# htmlspecialchars expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting the next error while printing a model content on my blade.php view:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

This model "content" is a column (json type) in a table and it looks just like this:

```
[{"Item":2}]
```

And this is how i'm trying to use it on my view:

```
@foreach ($post->loot->content as $name => $amount)
     <div class="item">
          <i class="fab fa-cuttlefish"></i>
          <div class="text">{{ $name }} <b>x{{ $amount }}</b></div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

For some reason, if i print $name alone, it shows the number (2) that should be printed while using the $amount variable.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: The error seems rather clear, you can't pass an array to the function, rather, it has to be a string.

Comment: But i'm using a foreach loop with an array. Laravel documentation on "Eloquent: Mutators" says the next things about array/json casting: "...adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model" So, technically, this: $post->loot->content should return an array with one (or more) object: {"Item":2} and my loop should print: $name = Item and $amount = 2. (Sorry for my bad english, not a native speaker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $post->loot->content  contains  [{"Item":2}]

It is an array of objects so, your $amount is the whole {"Item":2}, not 2.

so the loop can be something like:

```
@foreach ($post->loot->content as $id=>$json)
    @php
        $obj =json_decode($json, true)
    @endphp
    @foreach ($obj as $key=>$val)
     <div class="item">
          <i class="fab fa-cuttlefish"></i>
          <div class="text">{{ $key }} <b>x{{ $val }}</b></div>
     </div>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Not sure what you need but maybe you can swap

```
 <div class="text">{{ $key }} <b>x{{ $val }}</b></div>
```

with

```
   <div class="text">{{ $id }} <b>x{{ $val }}</b></div>
```

If you need the index of the whole object in the list instead of the attribute's obj key.

Comment: This one throws the next error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I'm using your answer with a change. Instead of using json_decode, i did this: $obj = (array)$json and it works just fine! Thanks !